# SymPy Taylor expansion for functions symbols

Tags: sympy, symbolic-math, maxima, taylor-series

How can you perform a Taylor expansion with respect to function symbols in SymPy?

For example

```
from sympy import *
ode = f(x).diff(x, 2) - sin(f(x))
```

We would like to linearize the differential equation by doing something like

```
ode.series(f, 0, 1)
```

to obtain something like

```
f(x).diff(x, 2) - f(x)
```

But I can't figure it out how to do this in SymPy. In Maxima, I could define a dependency like

```
depends(y, x);
ode: diff(y, x, 2) - sin(y);
taylor(ode, y, 0, 8);
```

and it would result in

```
'diff(y,x,2) - y + y^3/6 - y^5/120 + y^7/5040 + ...
```

This could be really useful to linearize non-linear differential equations or in perturbation theory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can temporarily replace `f(x)` by a symbol such as `y`, perform expansion with respect to that symbol, and then substitute back. Here is a self-contained example:

```
from sympy import *
var('x y')
f = Function('f')
ode = f(x).diff(x, 2) - sin(f(x))
ode_linear = series(ode.subs(f(x), y), y, 0, 2).removeO().subs(y, f(x))
ode_cubic = series(ode.subs(f(x), y), y, 0, 4).removeO().subs(y, f(x))
```

As a result, `ode_linear` is `-f(x) + Derivative(f(x), x, x)` and `ode_cubic` is `f(x)**3/6 - f(x) + Derivative(f(x), x, x)`